# Wrap single command as environment

Tags: environments

I am trying to define a `note` environment, currently it is just a wrapper of `\marginpar` function like this:

```
\newenvironment{note}{\marginpar}{}
```

but

```
\begin{note}
Important Notes
\end{note}
```

will only put *I* in the margin and the rest (mportant Notes) as normal paragraph.

I also tried

```
\newenvironment{note}{\marginpar\\{}{\\}}
```

which doesn't work.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx! I take it `\newenviorment` is just a typo and you really mean `\newenvironment`

Comment: You could use the `environ` package and do `\NewEnviron{note}{\marginpar{\BODY}}`

Comment: @clemens it works! I spent two hours workings in before posting this question. Thank you so much! Could you please write your solution as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`environ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package and do

```
\NewEnviron{note}{\marginpar{\BODY}}
```

---

```
\newenvironment{note}{\marginpar\\{}{\\}}
```

can't work! This misses the third argument of `\newenvironment`. And in the second you feed `\\` as argument to `\marginpar` (`\marginpar\\`), followed by an empty group (`{}`) and then by `\\` inside another group (`{\\}`). It looks to me as though you've tried to add `\marginpar{` as second argument to `\newenvironment` and `}` as third. (There are tricks to smuggle unbalanced braces into arguments of macros but that wouldn't help in this case…)